# Get non emptry cells of a range in an array

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to get all non-empty cells of a range.

```
    'get keywords - only non-empty values
    Dim sheetDataSource As String
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim keywords As Variant
    Dim strUrl As String
  '  Set sheetDataSource = "DataSource"
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Settings").Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
```

Currently, I get nothing back. Further, I would like to put them into an array to run over them with a for-loop.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: What should you get back? You're `.select`ing them

Comment: @Raystafarian I would like to have an array with all the values back that I can loop over.

Comment: What do you expect to get with the code above? You're not *getting* anything - you're just selecting it.

Comment: @Raystafarian I expect that it selects and *saves* me all strings in a certain cell to an array, where I can then loop over it in the next step. But currently this is not working.

Comment: [select](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291308) is an *action* - something that happens on the worksheet. If you need to do something else, you need to set a variable to that range instead of selecting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `Intersect` to get all non-empty cells:

```
With Sheets("Settings").Range("A2:A" & LR)
    Application.Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Select
End With
```

From here you can loop over this range rather than storing as an array (unless there's a specific reason you need it to be an array). Although I would also suggest not using the .Select method, but instead, set the desired range equal to a variable.

```
Dim NonEmpties As Range

With Sheets("Settings").Range("A2:A" & LR)
    Set NonEmpties = Application.Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
End With
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Would you be so kind to show an example for a for - loop in your answer!

Comment: I tried your example and I also get the error: "Argument not optional"

Comment: Thx for your edit. I still get: `Object variable or With Block variable not set`.

Comment: With `NonEmpties` as a range, you would need to `Set` it to the intersect.

Answer (score 0):

I like Dan's answer, but just in case you want to do a bit of experimenting with ranges:

```
selectedRange = Application.Selection

For Each cell In selectedRange

    If cell <> "" Then Debug.Print cell

Next
```

Highlight a range in the workbook, then flip to the VB Editor and run the code. It should print everything in the selected range except any cells that were blank.